# Locked achievement is not show up in the steam client, only number is shown

Tags: steamworks-api

Achievements exist in the Steam backend and is set to **client**. The game is not released yet. I know that the achievement locked is not gonna show up in the Steam client. But, why does the achievement locked not show up in the Steam client?

Only total locked number is shown. I found in other games that some locked achievements and the number remained are both there. How can I do that? 
Or is it because my game is not released yet?

Expected:

[image]

Actual:

[image]

Comment: Is there something wrong in the steam backend? Or some API should be call in my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official response：Until your game is released, achievements will not show up in the Steam Client. For the achievements to show up the achievement data has to be public and that won't happen until the game is released.

Comment: early access counts as released right?

Comment: Update: Yes it does.